# HTTP Status 404 on /alfresco

Tags: alfresco

I have installed Alfresco on port 8180 and it's not running. It's giving error HTTP status 404 at `/alfresco`.

`alfresco.log` output is:

```
13:56:20,665 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.admin] Using database URL 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/alfrescobo' with user 'alfrescobo'.
13:56:20,899 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.admin] Connected to database MySQL version 5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
13:56:27,524 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Starting 'sysAdmin' subsystem, ID: [sysAdmin, default]
13:56:27,549 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Startup of 'sysAdmin' subsystem, ID: [sysAdmin, default] complete
13:56:36,184 INFO  [org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.TemplateProcessorRegistry] Registered template processor Repository Template Processor for extension ftl
13:56:36,186 INFO  [org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.ScriptProcessorRegistry] Registered script processor Repository Script Processor for extension js
13:56:42,040 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap] Connecting to database: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/alfrescobo, UserName=alfrescobo@localhost, MySQL Connector Java
13:56:42,041 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap] Schema managed by database dialect org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect.
13:56:42,729 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap] No changes were made to the schema.
13:56:43,239 ERROR [org.alfresco.repo.dictionary.DictionaryRepositoryBootstrap] Failed to create model (due to EmptyContentReader): workspace://SpacesStore/154d07f2-fc85-4625-8197-6bfb7348a0ec
13:56:43,273 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Starting 'Authentication' subsystem, ID: [Authentication, managed, alfrescoNtlm1]
13:56:43,417 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Startup of 'Authentication' subsystem, ID: [Authentication, managed, alfrescoNtlm1] complete
13:56:43,684 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Starting 'Search' subsystem, ID: [Search, managed, solr]
13:56:43,941 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Startup of 'Search' subsystem, ID: [Search, managed, solr] complete
13:57:19,184 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] Context initialization failed
org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 02040119 Workflow deployment failed
    at org.alfresco.repo.workflow.WorkflowDeployer.init(WorkflowDeployer.java:345)
    at org.alfresco.repo.workflow.WorkflowDeployer$1$1.doWork(WorkflowDeployer.java:469)
    at org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AuthenticationUtil.runAs(AuthenticationUtil.java:548)
    at org.alfresco.repo.workflow.WorkflowDeployer$1.execute(WorkflowDeployer.java:465)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:452)
    at org.alfresco.repo.workflow.WorkflowDeployer.onBootstrap(WorkflowDeployer.java:460)
    at org.springframework.extensions.surf.util.AbstractLifecycleBean.onApplicationEvent(AbstractLifecycleBean.java:56)
    at org.alfresco.repo.management.SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEventInternal(SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.java:209)
    at org.alfresco.repo.management.SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.java:180)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:303)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:911)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:428)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.alfresco.web.app.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:976)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1653)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.ContentIOException: 02040118 Failed to open stream onto channel: 
   accessor: ContentAccessor[ contentUrl=store://2016/3/2/7/32/78b6eff0-8082-4ed5-9d43-d3adad1f6a6b.bin, mimetype=text/xml, size=0, encoding=UTF-8, locale=en_US]
    at org.alfresco.repo.content.AbstractContentReader.getContentInputStream(AbstractContentReader.java:401)
    at org.alfresco.repo.workflow.WorkflowServiceImpl.isDefinitionDeployed(WorkflowServiceImpl.java:273)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor341.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.alfresco.service.cmr.workflow.WorkflowPermissionInterceptor.invoke(WorkflowPermissionInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.alfresco.repo.security.permissions.impl.ExceptionTranslatorMethodInterceptor.invoke(ExceptionTranslatorMethodInterceptor.java:46)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.alfresco.repo.audit.AuditMethodInterceptor.invoke(AuditMethodInterceptor.java:161)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy57.isDefinitionDeployed(Unknown Source)
    at org.alfresco.repo.workflow.WorkflowDeployer.deploy(WorkflowDeployer.java:368)
    at org.alfresco.repo.workflow.WorkflowDeployer.init(WorkflowDeployer.java:324)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.ConcurrencyFailureException: store://2016/3/2/7/32/78b6eff0-8082-4ed5-9d43-d3adad1f6a6b.bin no longer exists
    at org.alfresco.repo.content.EmptyContentReader.getDirectReadableChannel(EmptyContentReader.java:56)
    at org.alfresco.repo.content.AbstractContentReader.getReadableChannel(AbstractContentReader.java:271)
    at org.alfresco.repo.content.AbstractContentReader.getContentInputStream(AbstractContentReader.java:375)
    ... 48 more
```

Comment: What version of Alfresco do you want to install? On what OS?

Comment: alfresco 4.2 on ubuntu 14.04 with mysql 5

Answer (score 1):

The file

```
alf_data/contentstore/2016/3/2/7/32/78b6eff0-8082-4ed5-9d43-d3adad1f6a6b.bin
```

has been deleted. We have no way to know what this file contained two day ago.

You will have to make a clean Alfresco installation and start again.

Comment: 5 -6 times i have done the clean installation but still the problem is same.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are completely wiping out the database and the content store between each installation. If this log is from a fresh install, I think it may be missing the schema creation step, which means the database already exists which should not be the case for a fresh install.

If you are clearing out the content store but not the database, Alfresco will look for nodes that exist in the DB but no longer exist on the file system, which is essentially a corrupted repository.